# Setting up a local PyPi server with custom set of packages

Tags: python, package, pypi

I want to set up a local PyPi server with a custom set of packages and all their dependencies.

What I have right now is a list of packages in format:

```
django==1.4.3
celery==3.0.12
uwsgi==1.2.6
pillow==1.7.7
...
```

and I would like to have a local PyPi server which can serve all these eggs and their dependencies.

How can I achieve this?

Ideally I would like to have a tool which can take requirements.txt file as an input, download all listed packages and copy them into a local pypi.

Answer (score 4):

You set up a [local pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver) server, and only provide those eggs and dependencies in the [repository](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver#managing-the-package-directory)...

All this is available through googling 'local pypi server'.

#### EDIT

It would be simple to write a script to parse your `requirements.txt` file and pull the packages into your local repository - but ideally this is something you will attempt yourself before asking for help with.

Comment: a script that generates a simple repository with N recent versions of 4000 most used packages on pypi. Advantage is it can hold multiple versions as in pypi. https://gist.github.com/harisankar-krishna-swamy/cac5d1e6c1ae074b39286c1336bff63d