# Unable to use --extra-index-url with pip after upgrading to 18.1

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I've created my own python wheel package and hosted it locally so that I can install it with pip using the --extra-index-url flag like so:

```
pip install --extra-index-url http://10.0.0.100:5000/ MyPackage --trusted-host 10.0.0.100
```

I have several dependencies that get installed and with pip version 9.0.1 this seemed to work fine; it would initially look for the dependencies at the supplied index, would get a 404 error because I am only hosting my own package, but then would try looking for it at the default index url, https://pypi.org/simple.

After upgrading to pip 18.1 however it throws an exception on the initial 404 error and cancels the entire install:

```
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: NOT FOUND for url: http://10.0.0.100:5000/urllib3/
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this the intended functionality?

Ultimately I want to be able to host a single package locally, use pip to download and install it but have any dependencies pulled from the default pip repo.  Is there another way to accomplish this?  Everything I have read says that --extra-index-url is the way to accomplish this but it no longer seems to be working...

UPDATE:

I tried to replicate this on another system and encountered the same issue using pip version 9.0.1 so it seems that the upgrade wasn't the root cause.  Strangely, after upgrading to 18.1 on this other system it worked fine...

Ultimately I was able to get the original system working by just uninstalling and reinstalling pip with easy_install.  I am still not sure what the underlying issue might be though...

To answer the comment, for this I was using Flask-AutoIndex to host the contents of a folder.  Not as simple as your solution I suppose but gets the job done:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_autoindex import AutoIndex

app = Flask(__name__)
AutoIndex(app, browse_root='packages')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=5005, threaded=True)
```

Comment: What custom PyPI server are you using? Can you reproduce the issue when using a [local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127695/2650249)?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem when trying to install another lib with pip 18.1. Upgrading to pip 19.2.3 solved the issue.